CIF file of Activated Carbon
i hope you all are good
any one who share me CIF file of activated carbon*emphasized text

I'd propose to first edit the question, then search the literature to learn more about the structure of activated carbon, and when you know more precisely what structure you're after, try searching CIF databases (COD, CCDC).

i'm so confused, I didn't find the cif of Activaated carbon  kindly plz help
